# Callback when all ajax is loaded

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have this code

```
var chapterNameArr = ['firstchapter','secondchapter','thirdchapter','fourthchapter','fifthchapter','sixthchapter','seventhchapter']; 


$.each(chapterNameArr, function( index, value ) {

    var $chapterCont = $("#"+value);

    $.ajax({
      url: "scripts/templates/"+value+".html",
      cache: false,
      success: function(data){
        var $data = $(data);
        $chapterCont.append($data);
      }
    });

});
```

I want to execute a function when all content from ajax calls are successfully loaded. How do I do that ?

Comment: Keep track of what is loaded in your `success` handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to invoke a callback once multiple requests are done, is to use jQuery $.when function:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

I really suggest you read through the documents regarding this function
and the 'deferred' concept ( http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Deferred )

Should be something like this ( just as an example )

```
var chapterNameArr = ['firstchapter','secondchapter','thirdchapter','fourthchapter','fifthchapter','sixthchapter','seventhchapter']; 
var pendingAjax = []

$.each(chapterNameArr, function( index, value ) {

    var $chapterCont = $("#"+value);

    var ajax = $.ajax({
      url: "scripts/templates/"+value+".html",
      cache: false,
      success: function(data){
        var $data = $(data);
        $chapterCont.append($data);
      }
    });

    pendingAjax.push(ajax)
});

$.when.apply($, pendingAjax).done( successCallback ).fail( failCallback)
```

Answer (score 0):

$.active returns the number of active Ajax requests. Use $.active==0 means no ajax requests are active. You could also use ajaxStart and ajaxStop to keep track of when requests are active

Code :

```
var ajaxRequestsTimer = setInterval(isAjaxRequestsCompleted, 10000);

function isAjaxRequestsCompleted(){
    if($.active == 0) {
        clearInterval(ajaxRequestsTimer);
        $(document).trigger('ajaxRequestsCompleted');
    }
}

$(document).on('ajaxRequestsCompleted',function(){
    // insert the code here to execute after all ajax requests completed

})
```

Comment: Thanks but can you explain with code please ? Not sure I understand

Comment: i updated my answer with code. Check it and let me know